# Purchasing a campervan in Australia

Tags: online-resources, australia, shopping, campers

My girlfriend and I are off to Oz at the start of January - looking to travel the East Coast in a campervan. The plan is to purchase one when we get there and was just wondering about the details.  I've been looking at [Gumtree Australia](http://www.gumtree.com.au/s-campervan/melbourne/campervan/k0c20011l3001317) and it seems a reliable, well maintained camper is in the region of $5800 - $7000? Has anyone had experience purchasing a camper out there - is there a common rate for a good affordable camper?

Apart from say, Gumtree/Ebay are there other common places for travellers to purchase? I'm hoping we will catch travellers leaving and looking to sell as we arrive. Also - at the end of the journey, (if we keep the camper in good condition) hopefully we can recoup some money we paid - do they depreciate in value at all?

Comment: Welcome.  I reworded your question to make it less subjective, and to try and not just have it as a 'polling for advice' question - both would be considered off-topic here (see [help]).  Hope the reword is ok with you.  (/waves from Melbourne - it's gonna be hot then!)

Comment: @Ankur-Banerjee I don't think your title change reflects their intentions - they are already going to buy one, they're trying to work out I guess how to do it more cheaply, reliably and safely.  The 'is it worthwhile' also turns it into a subjective question :/

Comment: @MarkMayo Edited it back to the non-question format. Case of TL;DR when editing. :)

Comment: If you want to stick near the coast, and the cost of buying + running the camper van is looking a little high, you could maybe buy a tent and something like the [east coast discovery train ticket](http://www.nswtrainlink.info/deals/travel_passes/east_coast_discovery) (or bus equivalent)

Comment: While there is nothing stopping anyone from buying a vehicle in Australia, the vehicle must be registered before it's driven on public roads. Depending on your residency status, you may not be able to register the vehicle or transfer its current registration to your name, as most (if not all) States require proof of ID which usually also requires proof of residence. If you're in Australia as a temporary tourist, that may be problematic. You would have the same problem upon resale.

Answer (score 5):

Gumtree's where it's at for both travellers and locals in Australia, it's the local version of Craigslist and Ebay rolled into one.

As for what the "right" price, you're buying a used car here, with all the caution that warrants.  But a few pointers:

- [Red Book](http://www.redbook.com.au/) is the standard source for used car values in Australia, although it'll be of limited use for highly customized vehicles like campervans.
- You'll definitely want to check out the vehicle's registration history and possibly get a pro to look at the vehicle itself. [CarsGuide](http://www.carsguide.com.au/tools-and-advice/hints-and-tips/how_to_buy_a_used_car_10_tips) has a handy checklist, the exact registration details vary considerably by state of registration.
- Try to avoid buying a car that's not registered in the state you're currently in, reregistering it in a new state entails a lot of expensive bureaucracy.

Answer (score 4):

would have to agree with the above answer. Gumtree is a good place to start your search for a camper or travel van purchase in that price range. Listings from private and commercial sales yards.

They have created a very thorough guide to campervan purchases as well, to avoid a dud; http://blog.gumtree.com.au/backpacker-guide-buying-van-aussie-road-trip/

Also a good place to resell after your trip. Not sure about depreciation. Depends on the model you purchase and condition / kms on the clock.